Vercel: Module Not Found
Im having this problem where the error declared that the module for react-redux and react-hot-toast not found. Already installed it and still having the same problem. Please help (-3-)
ERRORS
[09:18:19.997] 153 packages are looking for funding
[09:18:19.997]   run `npm fund` for details
[09:18:20.020] Detected Next.js version: 15.0.2
[09:18:20.024] Running "npm run build"
[09:18:20.555] 
[09:18:20.557] > client@0.1.0 build
[09:18:20.560] > next build
[09:18:20.562] 
[09:18:21.278] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[09:18:21.278] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[09:18:21.278] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[09:18:21.279] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[09:18:21.279] 
[09:18:21.339]    ▲ Next.js 15.0.2
[09:18:21.340]    - Environments: .env
[09:18:21.340] 
[09:18:21.418]    Creating an optimized production build ...
[09:18:52.597] Failed to compile.
[09:18:52.598] 
[09:18:52.598] ./app/Provider.tsx
[09:18:52.598] Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux'
[09:18:52.598] 
[09:18:52.598] https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[09:18:52.598] 
[09:18:52.598] Import trace for requested module:
[09:18:52.598] ./app/layout.tsx
[09:18:52.599] 
[09:18:52.599] ./app/components/Admin/Course/AllCourses.tsx
[09:18:52.599] Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast'
[09:18:52.599] 
[09:18:52.599] https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[09:18:52.599] 
[09:18:52.599] ./app/components/Admin/Course/CourseContent.tsx
[09:18:52.599] Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast'
[09:18:52.599] 
[09:18:52.599] https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[09:18:52.599] 
[09:18:52.599] Import trace for requested module:
[09:18:52.600] ./app/components/Admin/Course/EditCourse.tsx
[09:18:52.600] ./app/admin/edit-course/[id]/page.tsx
[09:18:52.600] 
[09:18:52.600] ./app/components/Admin/Course/CourseData.tsx
[09:18:52.600] Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast'
[09:18:52.600] 
[09:18:52.600] https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[09:18:52.600] 
[09:18:52.600] Import trace for requested module:
[09:18:52.600] ./app/components/Admin/Course/EditCourse.tsx
[09:18:52.600] ./app/admin/edit-course/[id]/page.tsx
[09:18:52.600] 
[09:18:52.600] ./app/components/Admin/Course/CreateCourse.tsx
[09:18:52.600] Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast'
[09:18:52.601] 
[09:18:52.601] https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[09:18:52.601] 
[09:18:52.601] Import trace for requested module:
[09:18:52.601] ./app/admin/create-course/page.tsx
[09:18:52.601] 
[09:18:52.616] 
[09:18:52.616] > Build failed because of webpack errors
[09:18:52.644] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[09:18:53.011] 

package.json
    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.6",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.22.2",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.8.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^4.9.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "next": "^15.0.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.10",
    "next-themes": "^0.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^0.7.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "recharts": "^2.13.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.8.1",
    "stripe": "^17.3.1",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

Provider.tsx
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { store } from "../redux/store"

interface ProviderProps {
    children: any;
}

export function Providers({ children }: ProviderProps) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
}


already install the latest version of react-redux and react-hot-toast.
already use git config core.ignorecase false


can you share package.json along with your ./app/Provider.tsx?

Sure but now I try to delete the project and deploy it again and it has the same error module not found

hi there!
Have you tried removing package-lock.json or yarn.lock, then deleting node_modules folder and then running a npm install (or yarn) again?
this will recreate the lock files and node_modules folder; then go into the node_modules folder and verify if the two packages are there.

GUYSS ITS WORKED... its look like vercel did not update my changes in git
THANKS FOR ALL THE HELPS GUYS
